# How do I refine and build on a basic scaffolding Dynamic Data project?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

Once you create a basic, generated dynamic data project with scaffolding, there are so many more things you can do to customise and improve the project, evolving toward a finely crafted custom application that benefits from reliable infrastructure.

You can add metadata for scaffolding tables, customise the standard list and details pages, customise template controls, etc.

What else can you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the two biggest items I can think of are:

- You can modify / define your own
  metadata provider.

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/08/dynamic_data_and_custom_metada.html - Names all columns with a space between words... Yes, you could use the DisplayName attribute but this is a sample of how to refine the basic scaffolding project.

- You can create your own attributes.

http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/04/hiding-foreign-key-column-globally-in.html - Sample of creating an attribute to hide the foreign key column for all tables.

http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/10/dynamic-data-hiding-columns-in-selected.html - Sample of another attribute to hide a column but applied at the page level.

After this, to get DD ready for the real world you can:

Tier it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/tags/Dynamic+Data/default.aspx

Mix it with Web forms, with MVC...
http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14473
See the samples.  Also in the samples is how to use Stored Procedures with it.

Use AJAX and/or JQuery.....

These are not DD specific modifications but likely necessary to be real world ready.

Here's a link that may help also:
http://blogs.msdn.com/rickandy/archive/2009/01/08/dynamic-data-faq.aspx